# How to get the results of a query as an Object from Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I migrated from firebase Realtime Database to Cloud firestore in one of my ReactJS projects. And I am fairly new to Firestore.

Here's what I need. Consider that I have details of items stored in a collection **'Items'**.

In Realtime database, I just had to do this to get the data and store it in the state:

```
database.ref('Items').once('value', (snapshot) => {
    this.setState({items: snapshot.val()})    
})
```

`snapshot.val()` returns all the objects in *Items* as a single object containing them. That makes it easy for me to render them in  a table with `Object.keys(this.state.items).map()`

#### From what I know so far:

This is not the case with Firestore. Firestore returns an object that can only retrieve the data in the child only by iterating through each one of them.

So the best I could come up with was:

```
db.collection('Items').get().then(gotData)
gotData = (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((item) => {
        const item = {[item.id]: item.data()}
        this.setState(previousState => ({
            items : {...previousState.items, ...item}
        }))
    })
}
```

The problem with the above solution is that the state will get updated a number of times equal to the number of items in the collection. So I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.  Of course, if you iterate all the documents in a collection, you'll be doing something once for each document.

Comment: I would like to know that if there is a way to set state only once, with all the objects in the collection like in the case of Realtime Database. ie. like all the objects are in `snapshot.val()` in realtime db

Comment: Set the state of what?  I don't really see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Its Reactjs. I want to fetch the data and store it into the state to render it inside a table.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fetch?  What does your datastore data look like?  It looks like you're fetching an entire collection, which means you're iterating each document in that collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost there, you just want to put the empty object outside the iteration like so...

```
db.collection('Items').get().then(snap => {
    const items = {}
    snap.forEach(item => {
     items[item.id] =  item.data()
    })
    this.setState({items})
}
```

Or you could just map it, which I find easier to think about.

```
db
 .collection('Items')
 .get()
 .then(collection => {
    const items = collection.docs.map(item => {[item.id]: item.data()})
    this.setState({ items })
 })
```

Or you can use **reduce** to return an object containing all the items.

```
db
 .collection('Items')
 .get()
 .then((collection) => {
     const items = collection.docs.reduce((res, item) => ({...res, [item.id]: item.data()}), {});
     this.setState({items})
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the right way. The first method worked. And the second method seems much cleaner. But the problem is that it returns an array of objects with the key as its index to access the data. So I searched a little bit and found a way to return an object as in the case of realtime-db's snap.val() with the **reduce** method. `itemsRef.get().then((snap) => { const items = snap.docs.reduce((res, item) => ({...res, [item.id]: item.data()}), {}) this.setState({items}) })`

Comment: Didn't realise you wanted an object. Thanks for updating the response. Glad I could help.